# Call instance declared in Main from outside method on Timer Event

Tags: c#, events, methods, timer

Its my first time working with Timers and I need to call an instance of a class declared in my Main. My program is a Quiddich game, and this is my Main.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QuiddichGame
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Timer aTimer = new Timer(1000);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            aTimer.Interval = 1000;
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Start();

            Championship champ = new Championship();
            game.GenerateTeams();
            Game game = new Game(champ.teams[0], champ.teams[1]);

            juego.CrearDisplay();
            game.CreateField();

            while (true) { int a = 1; }
        }

        //Actualization
        static private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //HOW DO I CALL THE "game" INSTANCE IN HERE??
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GrantWinney It seems he is still working on it pasting code from multilanguage sources.

Comment: The game class is a class I wrote and is on another file (it is working). The "juego" word was an error of mine, my code is in spanish and forgot to change that one (juego = game). Also, I wrote all the code by myself, maybe it is not very cool because I'm just new to c#. The answer bellow worked, will accept it as soon as i can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define game at the class level:

```
class Program
{
    private static Timer aTimer = new Timer(1000);

    //Define your game in the class
    private static Game game;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        aTimer.Interval = 1000;
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Start();

        Championship champ = new Championship();
        game.GenerateTeams();
        game = new Game(champ.teams[0], champ.teams[1]);

        juego.CrearDisplay();
        game.CreateField();

        while (true) { int a = 1; }
    }

    //Actualization
    static private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        game.DoSomething();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked :) . It was a very simple problem!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, don't make `Game` a field of the `Program` class.

Instead, use the [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has a constructor that takes an `object state`.

```
Game game = //...;
Timer t= new Timer(OnTimedEvent, game, 1000, 1000);
```

And define your [callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with this signature:

```
static private void OnTimedEvent(object state)
{
    Game game = state as Game;
    if(game != null)
    { 
        //...
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QuiddichGame
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Game game
        private static Timer aTimer = new Timer(1000);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            aTimer.Interval = 1000;
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Start();

            Championship champ = new Championship();
            game.GenerateTeams();// this should not be here
            Game game = new Game(champ.teams[0], champ.teams[1]);

            juego.CrearDisplay();
            game.CreateField();

            while (true) { int a = 1; }
        }

        //Actualization
        static private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //HOW DO I CALL THE "game" INSTANCE IN HERE??
        }
    }
}
```